# Компиляция WPF приложения из консоли

Tags: c#, wpf, компиляция

Приветствую,

Консольные и Windows Forms приложения компилируются с подключением нужных ресурсов без проблем. (Компилятор csc.exe)

Но возможно ли скомпилировать WPF приложение таким же образом?

Comment: Да. Если вы откомпилируете приложение с включенным log verbosity = maximum, оно покажет все запуски компилятора, ЕМНИП.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании MsBuild возможно и не такое